# Rate of convergence of Machine learning models

Tags: machine-learning, convergence

I am currently doing some work on the double debiased machine learning algorithm by [Chernozhukov et al. 2016](https://economics.mit.edu/files/12538). They achieve $ \sqrt{N} $ rate of convergence for estimation of a treatment parameter. Take as an example the following data generating process.
$$
Y_i=\theta D_i + g(X_i) + U_i
$$
where $ \theta $ is the parameter of interest and $ D $ and $ X $ are the treatment and the covariates respectively. $ D $ is generated by
$$
D_i = m(X_i) + V_i
$$
$ U_i $ and $ V_i $ are random disturbances. We have to estimate $ g(X) $ and $ m(X) $. The$ \sqrt{N} $ rate only holds if our ML algorithm converges with a  rate of $ n ^ {\frac{1}{4}} $.

So this was a bit of a stretch but now my question. Are there any reliable results for common ML techniques about their rate of convergence to the true function?

Comment: From my understanding, this paper positively answers the question for a class of deep neural nets: Farell, M. H., Liang, T., and Misra, S. (2019): "Deep Neural Networks for Estimation and Inference", [https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.09953](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.09953).